Halide CompileError thrown when compiling static library for RISC-V
I want to compile AOT a Halide function as a static library for RISC-V.
By following the tutorials I wrote the following configuration
target.os = Target::NoOS; 
target.arch = Target::RISCV; 
target.bits = 32; 
std::vector<Target::Feature> features; 
features.push_back(Target::NoRuntime); 
target.set_features(features); 
downcast8.compile_to_file("riscv_blur", {}, "downcast8", target);

But I get the following message when I run the produced executable
% terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Halide::CompileError' 
% Aborted (core dumped)

I tried compiling for other architectures like ARM and it worked fine but the RISC-V doesn't seem to work.
Is there an known issue with Halide and RISC-V or I did something wrong ?
EDIT:
So I was able to trace the exception and apparently Halide expects that vector_bits be set at a value v % 64 == 0 and v != 0.
So to my understanding is not able to run to a RISC-V system without the vector (RVV) extension. I am not able to find any official document that supports the above hypothesis but I am not able to compile to a static library unless I use the following configuration:
    Target target;
    target.os = Target::NoOS;
    target.arch = Target::RISCV;
    target.bits = 64;
    target.vector_bits = 64;
    std::vector<Target::Feature> features;
    features.push_back(Target::NoRuntime);
    features.push_back(Target::RVV);
    target.set_features(features);

    std::cout << target.to_string() << std::endl;

    try {
        brighter.compile_to_file("RISCV", {input, offset}, "brighter", target);
    } catch (Halide::CompileError& re) {
        std::cerr << re.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (Halide::InternalError& re) {
        std::cerr << re.what() << std::endl;
    }

    printf("Halide pipeline compiled but not yet run.\n");

This is also valid:
    Target target;
    target.os = Target::NoOS;
    target.arch = Target::RISCV;
    target.bits = 32;
    target.vector_bits = 64;
    std::vector<Target::Feature> features;
    features.push_back(Target::NoRuntime);
    features.push_back(Target::RVV);
    target.set_features(features);

    std::cout << target.to_string() << std::endl;

    try {
        brighter.compile_to_file("RISCV", {input, offset}, "brighter", target);
    } catch (Halide::CompileError& re) {
        std::cerr << re.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (Halide::InternalError& re) {
        std::cerr << re.what() << std::endl;
    }

    printf("Halide pipeline compiled but not yet run.\n");

So to extend my question even further. Does this mean that on a 64-bit system with 64-bits vector registers the processor does not need to support SIMD? A 32-bit system must support SIMD ?

Just because it "works" on one architecture does not mean that it works on another (or even the same one 6months later) - especially if your code contains undefined or implementation defined behavior, then all bets are pretty much off.

What I mean with "it worked for that arch" is that it successfully compiled for that arch. Not run, that is not my current goal. I basically followed the tutorial on this link from Halide's website https://halide-lang.org/tutorials/tutorial_lesson_11_cross_compilation.html

Can you find some more details about the exception you got? Trace it somehow. Hard to work with just a CompileError exception, best shot in the dark I have is that compiler has a bug or officially doesn't support some part of what you want.

I added further information, compilation worked after adding additional parameters.
